# Clone the tags in questions page, if the tags are not visible in the initial window

Tags: script, questions, tags

**About**

If the tags are not visible in the initial loaded page, this script will copy and paste the tags after the post title.

If the tags position is not less than the current window's height, then it will clone and paste the tags list.

If the tags position is less than the current window's height, it won't clone the tags list.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Clone Tags]

**Installation:**

[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/arulkumar4/StackApps/raw/master/CloneTheTagsInQuestions.user.js)

**Source code:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Clone the tags in Questions page
// @namespace   https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar
// @author      Arulkumar
// @description Clone the tags below the post title, if the tags are not visible in offset window
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/questions/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackoverflow.blog/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
(function ($) {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {

    if(($(window).height() - $(".post-taglist").offset().top) < 0) 
      $("#mainbar").prepend($('.post-taglist').clone());

    if($('.post-taglist').length > 1) 
      $('.post-taglist').first().css('margin-left', '58px');

  });
}(jQuery));
```